# How do I search for Opportunity record type ID references with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: apex

We want to deprecate 5 opportunity record types in our org, but we want to make sure no process builders, workflows, etc are currently referencing the 5 IDs. Salesforce support says there's no way to do this, but I read that using an IDE like Visual Studio can make is somewhat possible.

Can I use Visual Studio Code to search for Opp record type ID references throughout the org?

Comment: Yes you can. However you need to get a local copy of your salesforce's apex. That is a much larger question. [See this for starters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes, you can use VSCode to search for these.

Long answer, Visual Studio Code and the Salesforce Extension Pack will allow you to download your Salesforce org's metadata (via the Metadata API) to your local machine. Once you've retrieved the relevant metadata (Workflow Rules, Flows, etc.) using either a *package.xml* file or the Org Browser (provided by the extension pack) you can search through the metadata files with your ID.

Hit `CTRL+SHIFT+F` or the search button in the sidebar to search all the files in your workspace.

The [Quick Start: Visual Studio Code for Salesforce Development](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-vscode-salesforce) will walk you through all of the necessary setup and the pulling down metadata.

Comment: thanks. I did the trailhead. Extracted the org metadata via 'Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org' in VS code from sandbox. Is the process builder/flow metadata included in what was extracted?

Comment: @Nivi Like I said in the comment above, this is a much larger question. You should create a new question with any problems you run into after researching them.

Comment: FYI @TemporaryFix nbrown\'s solution worked - I just needed to Choose Metadata Components for Package.xml, which included workflows, flow definitions, etc. Thanks all for the help